# Problem with sending mail behind firewall

Tags: c#, email, firewall

I'm tired to send message over SSL with SMTP by i still have an exeption :

"Operation timed out"

My questions is :

- How to resolve this problem;
- How to send an email behind the firewall !!!

Thanks,

```
   public void SendMessage() 
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("servername.ru.alt001.com");
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ali.mselmi@server.ru","password");
        client.Port = 465;
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
        {
            Subject = "Test Message",
            Body = "Hello, this is a test !!! Kind Regards Ali Mselmi"
        };

        message.To.Add("ali.mselmi@gmail.com");
        message.From = new MailAddress("ali.mselmi@server.ru");

        client.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the point of a firewall - people can't reach a port behind it unless they're allowed to.

You'll need to contact the firewall owner/admin if indeed that's the problem.

The other possibility is that you have the wrong port number - 465 is the legacy port number for secure smtp - I believe 587 is the recommended port...

Comment: 465 is a secure SMTP port (deprecated; 587 is generally used now).  Either way, if the firewall isn't allowing port 465 outbound, this isnot a programming problem.